# std::pair as a template<class> argument? C++

Tags: c++, class, templates, std

I have a class that is a template, using the argument: `template <class X>`

Can I template this class to be of type `std::pair < W, Z>`? I am getting an unresolved external symbol error, and trying to track down the cause.

Comment: Pasting in your code would be nice :) but yes, you can do it.

Comment: Are you asking whether `X` can be `pair<W,Z>`? Yes, that's possible. Your error lies elsewhere.

Comment: Asking whether *abc* is possible is not the way to solve unresolved-external errors. To solve those, figure out what the linker is looking for and then try to find it yourself. If you find it, figure out why it's not being linked. If you don't find it, then define it so the linker can find it next time. You've asked a yes-no question, and whichever answer you get, you'll be no closer to solving your immediate problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little example of passing a pair into a template.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template <typename T>
class C {
    public:
        void add(const T& val) { m_vec.push_back(val); }
    private:
        std::vector<T> m_vec;
};

int main()
{
    C<std::pair<int, char> > pairC;
    pairC.add(std::make_pair(5, 2));
}
```

would instantiate a template class taking a  std::pair and holding it in a vector.  Add inserts a pair made with make_pair into that vector.

Note that for older C++ compilers you need to add a space between the two right-chevrons to stop it from being seen as a right-shift operator.